# полное удаление дубликатов

Tags: sql, sql-server

В таблице остались ненужные данные с одинаковыми задвоенными картами, к примеру :

```
fio             cards   login
Пупкин Пупка    333     user1
Пупкин Леха     333     user2
Соколова Ирина  444     user33
Иванова Дина    444     user4
Козлова Михаил  555     user5
Козлова Михаил  555     user7
Сахаров Иван    666     user10
Смирнова Ольга  777     user12
```

как лучше удалить все данные у которых совпадение по столбцу карты? что попадают под условие

```
SELECT cards, COUNT (*) AS Q
FROM Table
GROUP BY cards
HAVING  COUNT (*) > 1
ORDER BY cards
```

Comment: Я бы не советовал так чистить. Очень велика вероятность удалить актуальные сведения. И кстати с точки зрения БД, это никакие не дубликаты.

Comment: Дубликаты удаляем все? Или одну запись все-таки оставляем? Если да, то какую? Любую из дубля?

Comment: Дубликат - это когда ВСЕ поля имеют то же значение. У Вас - только 2 из 3. Если надо избавиться от ТАКИХ "дубликатов" - сформулируйте чёткий критерий, какую из записей следует оставить.

Comment: удаляем все! это будет в job после чистки,  этот запрос удалит ненужные оставшиеся косяки... так как  эти карты уже будут добавляться как новые к старой БД и задвоенности карт не нужно

Comment: *удаляем все!* Покажите конечное состояние, после удаления.

Comment: Может проще удалить просто все, и перезалить, раз это всё равно будет делаться?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если удаляем все, то вот так

```
DELETE FROM
  my_table
WHERE
  cards IN (
    SELECT
      cards
    FROM
      my_table
    GROUP BY
      cards
    HAVING
       COUNT (*) > 1
  )
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1273f/1)

Comment: Сахаров Иван 666 user10
Смирнова Ольга 777 user12
Должны остаться

Comment: @Be1m0nt Они и останутся. В чем проблема?

Comment: Вложенных запросов лучше избегать. Тормозят же страшно. Посмотрите мой вариант.

Comment: Anton Shchyrov не тебе а Akina писал,  у тебя да все норм с запросом - спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE t1.* 
FROM my_table t1 
JOIN my_table t2 ON (t1.cards=t2.cards AND t1.login <> t2.login)
```

Проверил на SQLFiddle  - работает. Важно, что не использует вложенных запросов

Answer (score 0):

Удалить все дубликаты по cards:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cards ORDER BY login) AS n
FROM my_table
)
DELETE cte WHERE n > 1
```

Comment: не так он оставит 1 из вариантов, а нужно удалить оба