# Удаление дубликатов SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Как удалить дубли из таблицы запросом SQL, оставив только одну из множества повторяющихся строк, если нет уникального ID?

Comment: DISTINCT? .....

Comment: Во-первых, определитесь с сервером - MS SQL и MySQL есть две большие разницы. Во-вторых, если MySQL - укажите точную версию.

Comment: MS SQL, исправилась.

Comment: distinct по какой-то причине не срабатывает(

Comment: @СветланаТинякова приведите пример входных и выходных данный, а также схему таблиц

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1085708/231582